# Basic Server-Protocol Relationship

Tags: networking, server, protocols, openssh

I am fairly new to networking and understand that a server is a host that handles requests made by clients. I also understand that protocols are the guidelines for handling these requests, however I do not understand why servers are described as (for example) SSH servers or FTP servers. My question is this: **Are servers limited to a specific protocol type or can the same server be able to use multiple protocols?**

Answer (score 0):

A server - roughly assimilated to a socket - is attached to a TCP or UDP port to listen for a (single) particular protocol on that port. Indeed once the socket is opened both parties need to agree on a common language to understand each other, otherwise communications magic will not happen.

Nonetheless multiple protocols can be stacked on a server as soon as both parties agree (and are aware of that). Think about TCP + SSL + HTTP + REST. Imagine also some kind of "master/super" protocol allowing parties to select a sub-protocol. This is possible ... but at the beginning one could say that this is a single protocol.